# PHP connect to Vertica in VirtualBox

Tags: php, windows, odbc, driver, vertica

I have problem with connection to Vertica database from PHP code. 
The situation is this:

I'm working on Windows 7,
I installed ODBC driver for Vertica, set it up and test connection was successful,
Vertica is running on virtual machine in VirtualBox, I can connect to it via ssh dbadmin@192.168.56.102.

I have tried all possibilities I've found but nothing worked. PDO cannot find server, odbc_connect is saying no driver exists.

Has anybody have idea please?

Thanks you very much.

J.

Comment: Could you add in the exact error messages you are getting?